# Replace parts of strings at given indices in a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I need help to replace a content in a list, but at a certain interval.

Lets say I have a list with this data:

```py
a = ["word word word" , "word data word"]
```

And I want to replace word that is in character `[9:13]` for data so the output of the list would be this:

```py
b = ["word word data" , "word data data"]
```

How could I do it in python? I've only found solutions that would replace everything that is named as word like the command replace.

Edit: I guess i tried to post a lighter version of my problem, I need to replace an invalid data for a valid data, but when I do it i can't risk replacing similar data that belongs there.

Replacing word for data in character [9:13]

a = ["word word word" , "word data othr" , "word, data word"]

Output should be:

b = ["word word data" , "word data othr" , "word, data data"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a list comprehension, slices and formatted strings:

```
a = ["word word word" , "word data word"]

b = [f'{s[:9]} data {s[14:]}' for s in a]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
['word word data', 'word data data']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i,v in enumerate(a): 
    a[i] = v[:10] + 'data' + v[14:]
```

then `a` will be:

```
['word word data', 'word data data']
```